# How can I iterate over a json without static main key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to iterate over a json object with multiple json objects inside, but **the main key who allow me to access to the objects is not static** , How can I iterate over those objects and at the same time to know the main key who allow me to have access to the object?

Thanks in advance

```
let res = {
     Zw== : { price: "500", code: "Zw==", name: "Word 2013", image: "path/d360f0.jpg", total: 1},
     aA== : { price: "300", code: "aA==", name: "Power point 2013", image: "path/80fa572.png", total: 1},
     xH== : { price: "300", code: "aA==", name: "Power point 2013", image: "path/80fa572.png", total: 1}
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but cant you parse the json to an object, and then just use `Object.keys`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Also please show some work of what you have tried.

Comment: That's an invalid Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your object properties look broken, so I would look into that.

I think what you're looking for is [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)..

Example:

```
function printKeys(obj) {
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
}
```

You can pass in your `res` object and it will give you have the property keys of the object.

From there then you can use the property as the next key.

`printKeys(res['Zw']);`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmd521fy/)